# Laravel: rendering partial views with AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a single page CRUD application and I am using AJAX with jQuery. In this case, I submit the form and store a new country in my database asynchronously and then render a partial view with the new data.

This is my script and the method that retrieves the countries from the database and returns the partial view.

```
$('#create-country-form').submit(function(event) {
    $.post('/country/store', $('#create-country-form').serialize(), function() {
        $.get('/country/all', function(data) {
            $('#countries-table').empty();
            $('#countries-table').append(data['html']);
        });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

class CountryController extends BaseController {

    public function all() {
        $countries = Country::All();

        $html = View::make('countries.list', compact('countries'))->render();

        return Response::json(['html' => $html]);
    }

    // ...

}
```

However, I don't like the idea of actually rendering the view in the page using jQuery, it feels like this should be Laravel's work.

How can I render with Laravel a partial view along with the use of AJAX, and not having to delegate that work to jQuery (`append()` and `empty()`)?

Comment: I agree it would be cool to have some sort of plugin for this. You could create a JS utility pretty easily I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confused.

Laravel *is already* doing the rendering of the partial. You are calling `View::make()` and returning the *rendered* view to `$html`.

Then you are passing the rendered view to jQuery, which is simply displaying the data given to it - its not doing any of the calculations itself.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that Laravel is rendering the view, but it has to be jQuery the one telling that that returned data has to be assigned to a particular DOM element. Can't Laravel do that with Blade?

Comment: No - AJAX is only possible through jQuery (or javascript). Laravel is PHP, so it can only be compiled once on the initial loading of the view. What you are doing is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: So the way I am doing it is the only way to do it? Also, regarding this matter, when showing session flash messages, since the page is not being reloaded, Blade @if and such won't be happening and I won't see those messages in the page. Should I return them from the controller and assign them to the page also using jQuery?

Answer (score 9):

Pass your view to view helper, render it into a variable and return that variable as response to AjAx.

```
$view=view('your-view-blade');
$view=$view->render();
$responseData->responseSuccess($view);
```

In callback of your AjAx you can use that rendered HTML, you are free to append that HTML to any element.

Answer (score 4):

Use string method before view file

```
return (String) view('Company.allUserAjax');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can render the view by `render()` function, then return it by JSON response

```
$arr['key1'] = value; 
$arr['key2'] = value; 

$view = view('view.name', $arr)->render();
return Response::json(['status' => 200, 'view' => $view]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing client with server.

1. You make the call from your client side, using jQuery, or Javascript fetch or whatever.
2. That request goes to an url, could be an API or a controller in your back end.
3. That controller will return the partial view.
4. You simply get the response on the ajax call success, then render it on the front end.

It's very simple and an efficient way to render content dynamically without refreshing the page. Just get what you need, saving bandwidth and loading time on the page.